# Do Windows GUI programs built with Cygwin require Cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, posix

Do straight Windows GUI programs (eg. not using POSIX) built with gcc/Cygwin have any *additional* dependencies compared to building with something non-POSIX (say, VS)?  If I build a "vanilla" Windows program with Cygwin will any Windows user be able to run it or will they require additional dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vanilla gcc, yes they will require cywgwin1.dll.If you use mingw-gcc, it will not, mingw will produce Windows program.

Also what do you mean "vanilla" Windows program?If you are talking about using windows headers like conio.h, no you can't build it.However in mingw they are avaible.

Comment: Well, the cygwin docs said its goal was to enable porting *nix programs to Windows (ie. Windows programs that have access to a POSIX API). That sounds like it would require some extra libs. My goal is full Windows development without needing to subject myself to VS and it sounds like MinGW is the way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would prefer MinGW to the VS compilers.  You don't have to use the GUI if you don't like it.  Note that MinGW uses the C runtime library that is built into Windows; strictly speaking, use of this library by third-party software is unsupported.  (The 32-bit version works OK and will probably continue to do so, but isn't supported.  The 64-bit version mostly works OK, and will probably continue to do so, though I have seen at least one developer run into trouble with it.)

Comment: I was finally able to come back to this and test it.  A simple "Hello, World!" program (not even GUI, yet) using only <iostream> and cout seems to require libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.  If I run the output .exe without that library present, it complains that it can't find it.  Even if I use -static-libstdc++, it still complains that it can't find that .dll if it's not present.  I've tried it both with and without statically linking libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and it always seems to require it in order to run.